# /Users/ /.zshrc:1: command not found: shell

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I'm new-ish to programming. For some reason shell isn't working in my terminal (mac os), iTerm2 or vscode terminals.

This is the error I get when opening a terminal:
Last login: Thu Jul  7 17:27:20 on ttys001
/Users/calereeves/.zshrc:1: command not found: shell
/Users/calereeves/.zshrc:source:75: no such file or directory: /oh-my-zsh.sh
calereeves@Cales-MacBook-Pro ~ %

When I run source ~/.zsh it won't work. But when I use vim ~/.zshrc this is what pulls up. The shell path on top I was told to use following the Meta Back-End Developer course. That's all that I've changed, and I don't even remember what was there originally.

```
shell PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:${PATH}" # If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
# export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
"~/.zshrc" 101L, 3928B
```

Either way, not sure why the shell isn't working in the first place. Any help is greatly appreciated. I can't even run the python shell.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This probably belongs to SuperUser, though I'm interested in what ```shell``` is supposed to be.   Since it's a PATH, I'd assume it'd be just ```export PATH=...```

Comment: _When I run source ~/.zsh_ : What is the content of file ~/.zsh? You have posted here only ~/.zshrc.

Comment: As _ewong_ said, the initial word `shell` does not make sense, and this is responsible for the error message. It just says that the command _shell_ is not found.

Comment: Aside from this, you have another error in line 75.

Comment: @user1934428 Yeah turns out I was taking things a little too literal with the instruction I was following...they put shell in the code box with the path so i just thought it was part of the line of code but they just meant to enter the path in the shell...‍♂️. Thanks for the responses! And yeah, somewhere along the way of figuring it out I managed to fix line 75 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and solved it after saw you guys' discussion.

> shell PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.x/libexec/bin:${PATH}"

Remove 'shell' in the Vim text editor.

> PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.x/libexec/bin:${PATH}"

In the course meterial, I think Meta should not put 'shell' in the grey block of codes. It is confusing.

Zsh

> shell source ~/.zshrc

Zsh Shell

> source ~/.zshrc